# Ошибка при компиляции проекта для Windows

Tags: c++, github

Компилирую проект [Efficient-Compression-Tool](https://github.com/fhanau/Efficient-Compression-Tool/tree/3eb2ad01b83145d6d1ebe6d4d7f02de80ac7bdc3) с помощью MSYS2

При запуске проекта получаю данную ошибку, как понимаю проблема в определенном файле, но как исправить не знаю.

```
C:\Users\Lorents>C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\ECT.exe C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\1001.png
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Users\Lorents\Desktop\ECT.exe
File: zopfli/lz77.c, Line 75

Expression: data[pos - dist + i] == data[pos + i]

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Почему?  Она весить все 10 кб.

Comment: @lorents Если кто-то будет искать ошибку по тексту, он ее не найдет.

Comment: Понял Вас! Исправил

Comment: Показана ошибка времени выполнения, ошибки компиляции нет. Предлагаю вам поменять тему вопроса, дабы она соответствовала ему.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он вызван нелокализованным багом в коде, который не приведен в самом вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ругани, проверяется какой-то внутренний тест, который затем роняет рантайм. Надежнее всего, написать все это дело (и не забыть скриншот) разработчику (или поискать в его багтрекере).

Comment: Написал об этом на форуме по данной программе автору, пока ответа нет. Я просто подумал, может я не правильно что-то делаю при компиляции. Я в этом деле не силен.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка связана с проверкой данных изображения.
Ты можешь определить препроцессорную переменную NDEBUG но это вряд ли решит проблему. Скорее всего просто избавит от сообщения, выдаваемого assert. Тем не менее сама программа может просто "рухнуть".

Comment: Как понимаю, лучше ждать ответа автора проекта. Сейчас напишу еще на github

Comment: Далеко не факт что проблема в библиотеке. Вполне возможно что проблема в изображении.

Comment: Не думаю, что проблема в изображении. Я перебрал несколько изображений, результат аналогичный.

Comment: Что будет, если определить NDEBUG?

Comment: Если подскажите, как это сделать, то я обязательно сделаю.

Comment: Добавь в Makefile, к переменным CFLAGS и CXXFLAGS флаг -DNDEBUG

Comment: Сделал, теперь проект ломает изображение, но не падает

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28914/discussion-between-lorents-and--).